# Magento 1.9 - Get new products

Tags: magento-1.9, php, products, new-products

How I can get new products of the last 30 days in Magento 1.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is an example you can try this, It will give you last added item of last 10 days.

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
umask(0);
$date = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d h:m:s');

$startDate =  Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d 0:0:0', strtotime($date." -10 days"));

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
 ->getCollection()
 ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $startDate, 'to' => $date));
 $collection->addAttributeToSort('entity_id', 'DESC');
```